# How to change encoding of attachments from sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server, encoding, sp-send-dbmail

Is there a way to change the encoding from default 'UniCode' to UTF-8 while generating data attachments from sp_send_dbmail on SQL Server? I found that there used to be a flag 'ANSI_Attachment' to accomplish just that but it got removed in SP2... Not sure if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

EXEC [msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186321.aspx)
        @parameter_name=N'DefaultAttachmentEncoding',
        @parameter_value=N'MIME',
        @description=N'Default attachment encoding'

Comment: hey Pavel, thanks for you suggestion. what should i pass in the @parameter_value so it encodes it in UTF-8? i did try "UTF-8" but it still encodes the files incorrectly. thanks :)

Comment: Did you try setting <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> in your html attachment?